# Get and Set XML elements with Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

NEWBIE QUESTION.

I haven't worked that much with xml, nothing like this anyway. I have some XML as shown below that I receive which has several namespaces.

I need to read some values, then update others before returning the revised XML with namespaces intact - don't want them removed.

I am given the path to some of the elements like this `cred/sub/aa` or `trip/items/item[0]/customerInfo/custName`.

But it seems that namespaces make it difficult to get to those elements so simply.

Does anybody know how I can read some of the values like `NON-SMOKING` from `custPref` or get the value `CABBAGE` from `bossman/zz`.

Also, I want to be able to then set a value such as `custName` to say `Mr. X`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<A1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <cred xmlns="https://blah-blah.com/?foobar">
        <sub>
            <aa>Zippo</aa> 
            <bb>lighter</bb> 
        </sub>
        <reqId>
            <cc></cc> 
            <dateOfBirth></dateOfBirth> 
        </reqId>
    </cred>
    <reqName xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">qwerty</reqName> 
    <reqId xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">12345</reqId> 
    <machine xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">
        <qqq>hello</qqq> 
        <www>goodbye</www> 
        <eee>99999</eee> 
        <rrr>88888</rrr> 
    </machine>
    <monkey xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">alskdjfhg</monkey> 
    <math xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">
        <language></language> 
    </math>
    <trip xmlns="http://blah-blah/simple">
        <tripOverview xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">
            <description></description> 
            <cost></cost> 
        </tripOverview>
        <bossman xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">
            <zz>CABBAGE</zz> 
            <yy>BANANA</yy> 
            <xx>MELON</xx> 
            <ww>SYRUP</ww> 
        </bossman>
        <items>
            <item>
                <itemSummary xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">
                    <description></description> 
                    <cost></cost> 
                    <reference></reference> 
                </itemSummary>
                <customerInfo xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">
                    <custName></custName> 
                    <custPref>NON-SMOKING</custPref>
                </customerInfo>
                <seatId xmlns="http://blah-blah/vader/base">1</seatId> 
            </item>
        </items>
    </trip>
  </A1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string xml = "<Root><Options></Options></Root>";

var xdocs = XDocument.Parse(xml);

xdocs.Descendants().Where(q => q.Name == "Options").FirstOrDefault().Value = "FoundIt";
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin, this has helped a lot, I have used your code above but just added the LocalName property i.e. `XElement xElement = xDocument.Descendants().Where(q => q.Name.LocalName == elementName).FirstOrDefault();`